# DataGridView shows some empty cells in first row after update

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My `DataGridView` is bound to a `BindingSource` which again has a `DataSet` as its `DataSource`. The corresponding `TableAdapter` in the `DataSet`has, amongst others, a `Fill` method which supplies data from an Access database. I fill my `DataGridView` with data as shown below:

```
myTableAdapter.Fill( myDataSet.MyDataTable);
```

All this works fine and as expected. The problem arises when I change my data using an `UpdateQuery` (which also works fine) and then click again into any of the rows in my `DataGridView` - as soon as I click, the last two cells of (always) the *first row* are shown as empty. No matter which row I click, it's always the cells in the first row and only after I perform the `UpdateQuery`.

When I check the Access database directly, everything is fine (ie the update succeeded). When I restart my application, everything shows up without any problems (until the next time I call `UpdateQuery` and click into my `DataGridView`).

I also tried calling ``` EndEdit()``and ```Refresh`on the`DataGridView`and calling`AcceptChanges()`on both the`DataSet`and the respective`DataTable` - nothing changed.

**Update**

The described behaviour only occurs after performing an `UpdateQuery`, `Insert`s and `Delete`s work without problem (data is updated correctly, no display issues).

**Update 2**

The problem also exists when I use different event handlers - originally I used `CellClick`, I also tried using `CellContentClick` and `CellMouseClick`. It even happens when I don't use the mouse at all but use the keyboard to navigate within the `DataGridView`.

It seems to be the case that "just" the display of my data doesn't work, what am I missing? The same error occurs in all of my `DataGridView`s I'm using in my form, no matter how simple or complicated the data is I'm querying / updating.

Comment: Try to set BindigSource.AllowNew = false

Comment: @daniele3004 - tried that, didn't work (as expected - why should that make a difference?).

Comment: I use BindingSource loaded with a List or Array. In my case it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be some nasty behaviour of the `TextBox.Clear()` method. I add more information below that I didn't deem necessary when posting my question:

Under my `DataGridView` I have some databound `TextBox` controls - the databinding was defined like

```
txtSomeId.DataBindings.Add( "Text", myDataGridView.DataSource, "ID" );
```

After calling the `UpdateQuery` method I reloaded the data (fine) and then cleared the content of those `TextBox` controls:

```
txtSomeId.Clear();
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.clear(v=vs.110).aspx), this method

> "Clears all the content from the text box".

This is all information the page provides. Removing those lines of code, all works as expected and there are no more problems.

That calling the `Clear` method also means that the databinding gets partially(?) removed is something I did not expect.

I wrote "partially" as the binding still works for the other rows in the `DataGridView` and the `TextBox` controls, just not for the first one (and here only for some cells). This is a very strange behaviour in my opinion, maybe someone else could shed some more light on this.